# Displaying multiple post types on home page

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, get-posts, loop

I've read several examples of how to do this but I still can't get it to work - each time I use get_posts() it seems to only keep and display the first set of results.

loop.php

```
function home_index() {

global $post;

echo '<ul>';

$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 3,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'gp_news',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id',
    'meta_value'      => 1,
    'meta_compare'    => '>='
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<li>';

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumbnail' );
    }
    ?>
    <h1>news <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php esc_attr(the_title()); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue...</a>
    <?php
    echo '</li>';
}

$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'gp_competitions',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id',
    'meta_value'      => 1,
    'meta_compare'    => '>='
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<li>';

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumbnail' );
    }
    ?>
    <h1>competition <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php esc_attr(the_title()); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue...</a>
    <?php
    echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';   

}
```

Comment: can you check your error log for apache?

Comment: I tried it myself and it worked. What does a `var_dump()` of the `$myposts` variables say?

Comment: The var_dump's of $myposts are all identical. Maybe it's got something to do with being in the loop.php file itself?

Comment: It doesn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out 2 ways of doing it. The first way is...

```
global $wp_query;

$args = array(
    array(
        'numberposts'     => 3,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_type'       => 'gp_news',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id',
        'meta_value'      => 1,
        'meta_compare'    => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'numberposts'     => 1,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_type'       => 'gp_competitions',
        'post_status'     => 'publish'
    )
);

echo '<ul class="hp_minifeatured">';
$temp_query = clone $wp_query;
for($index = 0; $index < count($args); $index++) {
    $myposts = new WP_Query( $args[$index] );

    if($myposts->have_posts()) {
        while($myposts->have_posts()) {
            $myposts->the_post();
            echo '<li>';

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumbnail' );
            }
            ?>
            <p><?php echo($args[$index]['post_type']); ?></p>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php esc_attr(the_title()); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue...</a>
            <?php
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
}
$wp_query = clone $temp_query;  
echo '</ul><div class="clear"></div>';
```

...but this results in using multiple queries.

Another way is...

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;

$querystr = "(SELECT wp_posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wp_posts, $wpdb->postmeta wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id and wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' and wp_posts.post_type = 'gp_news' and wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' and wp_postmeta.meta_value >= 1 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 3) union (SELECT wp_posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wp_posts, $wpdb->postmeta wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id and wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' and wp_posts.post_type = 'gp_competitions' and wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' and wp_postmeta.meta_value >= 1 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1)";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($pageposts) {
    foreach ($pageposts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<li>';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumbnail' );
        }
        ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php esc_attr(the_title()); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue...</a>
        <?php
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to query two custom post types by using this line:

`AND wposts.post_type IN ('custom_post_type_1', 'custom_post_type_2')`

This worked for my situation, where each custom post type was being sorted by the same meta_key

Comment: How did you insert this query part into the main SQL query? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do all that. The below function will allow you to control what shows up in the default loop without having to rebuild the query itself

```
function cpt_pre_get_posts_filter( $query ) {
  global $wp_query;

  if ( !is_preview() && !is_admin() && !is_singular() && !is_404() ) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
    /* set your post types in the array below */
    } else {
      $my_post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
      if ( empty( $my_post_type ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type' , 'my-post-type', 'my-other-post-type' );
    }
  }

  return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'cpt_pre_get_posts_filter' );
```

Comment: I don't think that will achieve what I want. I want each post type shown in that order, not mixed together. And you'll notice the first post type shows 3 post and all the rest just show 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = aray(
'post_type' => array ( 'post', 'page','event')
);
query_posts($args);
```

[Source](http://www.peterrknight.com/how-to-query-multiple-custom-post-types-with-query_posts-wordpress-tip/)

Comment: [You should not be using `query_posts`...](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/9364)